# NSDateFormatter issue involving week numbers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

On my machine (regional settings United States), the default "short" date format is set to "1/5/13" (month/day/year).

In the System Preferences, I have appended to it a week number, "1/5/13 1".

My problem is this code, where I try to convert a string to a date:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1/5/13 1"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
Date: 2000-01-01 05:00:00 +0000
```

That's **2000**, which is not even close to **2013**.

What is causing this problem?

Comment: why the flip do u add this number? use nsdateformatter to get it. btw: you should use `-dateFromString:`. I think, you should consult the docs. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: @vikingosegundo I changed the code to use `dateFromString:`, the result is the same. The point is not that I'm adding this week number :) The point is that my **users** have added this week number in their System Preferences and my app is not turning it into a correct date.

Comment: I did the same thing in system preferences, and then set up a short style date formatter, then ran `NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NDate date]]; NSDate *parsedDate = [formatter dateFromSTring:dateString];` and saw the same issue. `dateString` was formatted according to my preferences, but the formatter would not parse that same string correctly! I tried other changes to the style as well as other styles, and `CFDateFormatter`, with the same result! Perhaps it's a framework bug?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yes it's really strange. You can also try appending other things to the date instead of the week number, such as "Day of week", "Week of month", etc. Many of these also have serious issues. `dateFromString` simply does not read them correctly.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work either is getting the date format from the one created with the short style and then setting that as the format for a different date formatter that tries to parse the output of the first... very weird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm late to this discussion, and have seen a number of solutions offered, but what I see wrong with them all is that two incompatible date format elements are being used together. Your original approach failed because the string from which you're attempting to get your date doesn't match what `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` provides for.

If you're going to evaluate the week of the year, then you've got to use the capitalized form of the year; this provides for a "Week of Year" kind of calendar.

Let's re-work your original code a bit to include the new format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY w"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1/5/13 1"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Note that I'm using that capitalized form for the year. With 1 for the week of the year, I get this:

```
Date: 2013-01-05 08:00:00 +0000
```

and with 2 for the week of the year:

```
Date: 2013-01-12 08:00:00 +0000
```

and with 3:

```
Date: 2013-01-19 08:00:00 +0000
```

Makes sense, doesn't it? The day in the date increments by seven days with each increment by one of the week of year. The time's dorked, of course, but we never discussed anything to evaluate in that area, did we?

Comment: +1 this is pretty much how I'd do it.  Make sure you account for differing locales by setting the `locale` property of the formatter to the locale represented by the date in the string you're parsing, however.  This would totally fail if (for example) I were in Thailand, where the year 2013 was over 500 years ago.  Generally, setting the locale to `en_US_POSIX` works well for computer-generated date strings.

Comment: "Your original approach failed because the string from which you're attempting to get your date doesn't match what NSDateFormatterShortStyle provides for." Could you explain that assertion in more detail?

Comment: @CarlVeazey the ShortStyle can be any number of variations (because it can be modified by the user on OS X) and would also never include the week number.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Thanks; couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @DaveDeLong but that's the crux of the problem - when you modify short style in system preferences to include week number, short style formatters no longer parse date strings they themselves produced. The OP question was not super explicit but the string passed to dateFromString: was generated by a short style formatter after modifying the style in system prefs

Comment: @CarlVeazey yep! That's why you use the styles for formatting dates for *display*, and generally not for *parsing* them manually.

Comment: @DaveDeLong So if I want to *edit* a text field that uses the short-style format for *displaying*, I must somehow parse the format string myself and manually remove everything except the year, month and day, and use that *new format string* for the editing? Seems to me this has to be done to accommodate these rare cases where users add week numbers into the short-style format string in System Preferences.

Comment: @cocoa.doc on Mac you'd use an `NSDatePicker` (or attach an `NSDateFormatter` to the field and let it do the validation).  On iOS you'd set (simplistically) a `UIDatePicker` to be a `UITextField`'s `inputView`.

Comment: @cocoa.doc Looks like you want @"M/dd/yyyy w", with no padding for the month and a 4-digit calendar year. Also, be aware whether your "week number" refers to the week of year, in which case the lower-case w will work, or to the week of month, in which case you should use an upper-case W. There's a table for date specifiers under Appendix F, Date Format Patterns, at this link: (http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Display_Name_Elements)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateComponents *cmp=[[[NSDateComponents alloc]init]autorelease];
[cmp setWeek:1];
NSCalendar *cal=[[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *dte=[NSDate date];
NSDate *weekDate=[cal dateByAddingComponents:cmp toDate:dte options:0];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY"];
NSString *strDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:weekDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", strDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `dateFromString` method of `NSDateFormatter`...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1/5/2013"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate);
```

If you want to play with week number then use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` based on your need... (refer this code snippet)

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger week = [components week];
```

I hope this helps.