# NSDateFormatter is returning wrong Date on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a date formatter like below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *formatStr;
formatStr = @"yyyy-ww"; // WeekOfYear
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatStr];
```

and I use it like this:

```
NSDate *firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-01"];
```

However, when printing firstDate, it shows:

```
(lldb) po firstDate
2014-12-27 16:00:00 +0000
```

I don't know where I did it wrong, but I will never say 2014-12-27 is the first week of 2015.

Could someone help? Big thanks!

Comment: Actually specific to iOS 8.3? Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: I don't have other machine to test, but it is on iOS 8.3

Comment: oops, Seems I should use YY instead of yy

Comment: found another post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193795/nsdateformatter-issue-involving-week-numbers

Seems I should use YYYY, not yyyy

Answer (score 0):

In your device Goto

Settings > General > International > Calendar.
Make sure Gregorian is selected.

If anything other than Gregorian is selected, then your device will convert it into date based on that calendar

Use this [link](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) to know about date formats in IOS